# How to define a python function so its type is "type"?

Tags: python, class, types, meta

When defining a class Foo, or function Bar, I get:

```
>>> import MethodType
>>> type(Foo)
classobj
>>> type(Bar)
function

>>> type(MethodType)
type
```

My question is, how do I define a class/function myself, so that its type is "type"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't inherit from `object` when defining your `Foo` class:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
```